# How can I restart Unity/GDM when I get a blank screen after suspend?

Tags: 12.04, suspend, lightdm

Occasionally, with Ubuntu 12.04, I get a blank screen when I resume from suspend. I can see the mouse cursor, but that's all.

I can get TTY terminals, so is there a way to restart the graphical front-end from the command line? I know this was possible back with Gnome, but am not sure with Unity.

Comment: You might wish to log into launchpad and mark that this bug affects you too, if you haven't already: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/966744

Answer (score 10):

GDM is replaced by lightdm. If you haven't changed it manually.

STOP

`sudo stop lightdm`

START

`sudo start lightdm`

As far as I can remember, it has restart also. Try with following

RESTART

`sudo restart lightdm`

Comment: Thanks - that seems to be what I was looking for. I'll try it next time the problem emerges

Comment: If anybody finds this with a similar problem, Web-E's solution works perfectly

Comment: Ups, it destroys my settings. Is there another command to reset by maintaining my settings? Or is there anything I can do to load my settings back?

Comment: `unity --reset` is the command that causes resetting all values. Try without it. :)